# How to avoid in Angular testing phase having the following issue: Chrome Headless have not captured in 60000 ms, killing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner, google-chrome-headless, karma-webpack

It usually happens only in Jenkins, and to me it seems that Karma is trying to launch testing while the generating bundle process is on its way to get completed, so I was wondering whether there is a way to make Karma to use an existing bundle, or generate a bundle first and then launch karma using that bundle.

Error

```
[2021-06-10T15:51:24.567Z] [Exec Stream Pumper] [INFO] - Generating browser application bundles...
[2021-06-10T15:51:25.504Z] [Exec Stream Pumper] [INFO] 10 06 2021 15:51:25.405:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v6.1.2 server started at http://localhost:9876/
[2021-06-10T15:51:25.504Z] [Exec Stream Pumper] [INFO] 10 06 2021 15:51:25.409:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers ChromiumHeadless with concurrency unlimited
[2021-06-10T15:51:25.504Z] [Exec Stream Pumper] [INFO] 10 06 2021 15:51:25.423:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser ChromiumHeadless
[2021-06-10T15:52:26.231Z] [Exec Stream Pumper] [INFO] 10 06 2021 15:52:26.168:WARN [launcher]: ChromiumHeadless have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
[2021-06-10T15:52:33.103Z]  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFi[Exec Stream Pumper] [INFO] 10 06 2021 15:52:32.846:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start ChromiumHeadless again (1/5).
[2021-06-10T15:53:48.835Z] [Exec Stream Pumper] [INFO] 10 06 2021 15:53:47.634:WARN [launcher]: ChromiumHeadless have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
[2021-06-10T15:53:51.370Z] [Exec Stream Pumper] [INFO] 10 06 2021 15:53:51.295:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start ChromiumHeadless again (2/5).
[2021-06-10T15:54:48.318Z] [Exec Stream Pumper] [INFO] ✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
```

I don't know if this is related with the fact that it takes 3min to generate the bundle.

package.json

```
"karma": "~6.1.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
"karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
"karma-junit-reporter": "^2.0.1",
"karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32"
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen locally as well? How many unit tests do you have?

Try updating `karma-chrome-launcher` and maybe `karma` as well in `package.json`.

If it happens only on `Jenkins`, then I think you need a computer/agent on `Jenkins` with better CPU and more RAM.

Comment: Only on Jenkins with 240 tests

Comment: I updated my question with versions of different Karma packages

Comment: If it only happens on Jenkins, try to simulate the same machine locally but this will be difficult to do. Try to use a different Jenkins machine/agent with a better CPU and more ram and see if that helps.